# Ruby on Rails SQlite 3 database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been looking online about how to do queries for Ruby on Rails and I can find information how to build the query but not where I put the physical code.  I am very new to Ruby on Rails.

I have one database called story and it has the title and content columns that I made.  I have a page that is used to input the title and content and then stored into the database and then I have a page which displays all contents of the database but I do not understand how to do a query to find let's say, "a record that has a content or title that contains a certain word or phrase"

```
   <%= @story.content %>
```

So i understand that displays the content on the screen, do i just do the same thing for queries?

Comment: Have you created any controllers? You can't (shouldn't) execute SQL right on the page like some do in PHP.

Comment: woz is correct. your queries belong in your controllers, which expose the data then displayed in your views.

Answer (score 3):

In rails active records are used not direct sql queries

here's a good link that explains it ......

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

For example lets say you have post model and you want

1. Index all posts then use

   @posts = Post.all
2. you want to show specific post ,find it by id

   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
3. create a new post by

   @post = Post.new

Comment: under my app/models I have a story.rb and it contains the story class which inherits from ActiveRecord.  You said I need to do @story = Story.all but where do I put that?  Do I put that in the view of the page so it gets posted on the page? Or do I put it in the class?  I don't understand how I get the query displayed on the page

Comment: You have to put '@story = Story.all' in your controllers index action and call '@story' in view to index stories

Answer (score 1):

As per your query, In your controller Write like

```
@stories = Story.where("stories.content IS NOT NULL")  #Records those has a content
@stories = Story.where("stories.title LIKE%a_certain_word_or_phrase%") # Records that contains a certain word or phrase
```

If you want to pick up only one recoed from the databse you can user .first .last for example

```
@sotory = Story.where("stories.content IS NOT NULL").first #first item which has content
@sotory = Story.where("stories.content IS NOT NULL").first #last item which has content
```

You can also find by id like

```
@story = Story.find(1) # finds the record with id = 1
```

and so on ......

I think you need a good tutorial.As you are a newbie please checkout [Ruby on Rails Guides: Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)